# Validation(XHTML5): Element 'md-content' is not supported

Tags: html, angularjs

**What to do to solve this problem?**

*My Code is as below:*

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController" class="inputdemoIcons" data-layout="column" data-layout-padding="">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <md-content class="md-no-momentum">
        <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
            <label>Name</label>
            <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_person_24px.svg" class="name"></md-icon>
            <input data-ng-model="user.name" type="text"/>
        </md-input-container>
    </md-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, do not use `md-content`, it doesn't exist.

This is a list of available elements: https://github.com/angular/material2#feature-status

Comment: Thanks for your msg, But i couldn't get the result.

Comment: Well, you need to not use `md-content`, that's it.